# My shell prompt changed into a $ instead of the path that I'm working on

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu

When I write `vim foo;sh` by mistake instead of `vim foo.sh`, I can't see the path of my commands anymore.

For example my terminal used to have

```
username@username-VirtualBox:~Desktop/
```

and now it's just

```
$
```

How can I undo this? It's so annoying. I always have to stop the terminal and run another one to fix this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you type in `vim foo;sh`, you're actually running two commands separated by the `;`, it's the same as

```
vim foo
sh
```

and the second command starts a new shell, probably `dash`, which is configured with a different prompt.

Type `exit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or press <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd> to return to your parent shell.